# Destructive Wrath on spells cast from items

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature

The wand of lightning bolt just made an appearance in my game from a random loot table. My cleric would like to know if the channel divinity destructive wrath feature of her class is applicable to the spell cast from the wand? I believe it should be because I can't find any reason why it wouldn't be, but I'm also of the mind that there might be some sort of a hidden caveat somewhere about the source of the spell.

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but If the linked question doesn't answer yours, feel free to leave a comment or edit the question explaining why